# What happens when you increase default font size in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fonts, accessibility, uiaccessibility

**Note: this is not the same question as [Understanding default font sizes in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46794199/understanding-default-font-sizes-in-react-native)**

I have a React Native app that has a few `<Text/>` components of sizes, 12, 18, etc. When I increase the default font size to max in the phone's accessibility settings, the font all appears much bigger, but devtools still tells me it's the same size I set it to, 12, 18, etc. My questions are:

1) In what way does React Native change the font sizes when you increase the phone's default font size?

2) Why does devtools still show font sizes to be the same as I set them in my code, even though the text all appears bigger now?

If you can share any insight or point me to any useful resources, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your font size same as that your, you can add the following code to your root class.

```
 Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {};
 Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```

It will keep your `<Text>` component font size that you added.